# Error uploading archive to itunes

Tags: ios, swift, testflight

The errors are in the screenshots attached.

[image]

Here is some more info

1. My xcode version is Version 6.4 (6E35b) and the project uses swift (shown in the images)
2. The deployment target for both Pods and the application is set to 8.0 .
3. I have greped the entire project for MinimumOsVersion (and keyword likes), while not having found them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by taking following steps.

(1) removing references (deleting) to everything under (a) Frameworks folder and (b) Pods folder.

(2) removed all steps related to Pods/Frameworks from 'Build phases' in project settings, there were 3 steps that i had to remove (one checked podfile.lock, one to link with the frameworks and one to copy resources from frameworks)

(3) I manually installed the swift files into the project so that I dont have to use Frameworks.

I was able to upload the project archives to itunes without a problem.

I also changed the deployment target to 7.1 (ps.. in the 'General' Tab in project settings) (NOTE: not because its needed, but because I wanted to support 7.1 aswell).